# How to use the Logger.getLogger(Class clazz)

Tags: log4j

I'm trying to understand what Logger.getLogger(Class clazz) method does.

Is this getting the ROOT LOGGER and then using the passed in class name for printing to the log so you can track where a log call was made from?

How can I specify a different log name but also use the class naming?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Logger.getLogger(Class c) is just shorthand for Logger.getLogger(c.getName())

Class c.getName() returns the name of the entity represented by this Class object as a String.

It is not getting the root logger and adding the class's name to the output. Logger.getLogger(String s) will return a logger named according to the value of 's' if one exists, or it will create a new logger and associate it with that name.

You can configure your loggers to output differently based on their names, and you can make up whatever kind of names you want. If you want to specify a different name that includes the class name, like Foo::MyClassName, you could do Logger.getLogger("Foo::"+c.getName()).